# How do I make a dynamically created SPList read-only in browser, but editable in code?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development, list, splist

In code, I create a `SPList`. I write to this list programatically, but I would like the list to appear read-only for all users (perhaps excluding admins only) **in browser only**, i.e. I don't want to allow neither item editing nor adding new records from the site.

Creating the list works fine:

```
web.Lists.Add(listName, description, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
SPList newList = web.Lists[listName];

newList.Fields.Add("Field 1", SPFieldType.Text, true);
newList.Fields.Add("Field 2", SPFieldType.Note, true);            
newList.Fields.Add("Field 3", SPFieldType.Note, true);            

newList.WriteSecurity = 4; // "Users cannot modify any list item." - MSDN
web.Lists[listName].Update();
```

However, the created list is not read-only: items there can be edited and "Add new item" link is still visible at the bottom and working.

Is this possible to achieve? Disabling "Add new item" would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Have you thought about breaking permission on the list, and assign read only permissions? Then in code you can modify by using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: @RobertLindgren exactly what I was going to suggest:-)

Comment: Hehe @NadeemYousuf, it feels like a more Sharepointy approch

Comment: I actually have considered this. :) I'm writing to list using elevated privileges anyway. What I don't know is how to break permissions correctly, without potentially breaking up something else too (e.g. ending up with total read-only access even for RunWithElevatedPrivileges).

Comment: Thatäs nothing to be afraid of! Use BreakRoleInheritance(false) and then assign read permissions to the users that should have them